# LDAP UnboundId: get all values of attribute from single entry

Tags: java, ldap, unboundid-ldap-sdk

I have this code

```
    // get the search results, getConnection = LDAPConnection
    SearchResult searchResults = getConnection().search(basedn,
            SearchScope.SUB, "(cn=JacobKranz)", "description");

    System.out.println(searchResults.getEntryCount());
    if (searchResults.getEntryCount() > 0)
    {
        for(int i=0; i < searchResults.getEntryCount(); i++)
        {
            //System.out.println(i);
            SearchResultEntry entry = searchResults.getSearchEntries().get(i);

            System.out.println(entry.getAttributeValue("description"));

        }

    }
```

The entry where cn=JacobKranz has multiple descriptions added to it yet I am only able to get the first value rather than cycle through each one.

How would I go about getting all values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the multi-value API:

```
for(String v : entry.getAttributeValues("description")) {
    System.out.println(String.format("description value: %s", v));
}
```

Comment: I knew it was something simple that I was overlooking.  Thanks!